# How to refine last but one?

Tags: sql, teradata

I have the following table . I need to get the last but one event associate for each event

```
event_id    event_date  event_associate
1           2/14/2014   ben
1           2/15/2014   ben
1           2/16/2014   steve
1           2/17/2014   steve   // this associate is the last but one for event 1
1           2/18/2014   paul
2           2/19/2014   paul
2           2/20/2014   paul    // this associate is the last but one for event 2 
2           2/21/2014   ben
3           2/22/2014   paul
3           2/23/2014   paul
3           2/24/2014   ben
3           2/25/2014   steve   // this associate is the last but one for event 3
3           2/26/2014   ben
```

I need to find out who was the last but one **event_associate** for each event . The result should be

```
event_id      event_associate
1             steve    
2             paul
3             steve
```

---

I know in order to do this I need to maximize **event_date** and exclude the last **event_associate**

So I tried

```
SELECT event_id , event_associate
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE event_date = MAX(event_date)
)
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY  event_id ORDER BY event_date DESC) = 1
```

But I do not know how to use `EXISTS` in this case .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are quite close, you just need the 2nd row based on ROW_NUMBER:

```
select t.*,
   row_number() 
   over (partition by event_id
         order by event_date desc)
from tab as t
qualify
   row_number() 
   over (partition by event_id
         order by event_date desc) = 2
-- or simply
-- qualify rn = 2
```

Comment: Thank you . How can I get the row_number in the select ? `select * , row_number()  ...` I tried it does not work

Comment: Oh, i see. You need to use an alias, i modified my answer.

Comment: I rechecked it again and it is not working well . Did you mean `..... partition by event_id , event_associate ...` ?

Comment: No, this query returns exactly what you requested. If this is not correct, you should rephrase your question.